# How can I write a Pandas Dataframe containing a dictionary to Bigquery?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have JSON data from API which contain page number called 'offset' and 'items' which is a nested JSON like below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 20,

        "items": [
            {
                "id": "6biewd5a",
                "title": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
             },
                {
                "id": "er45ggg",
                "title": "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"
             }
                 ]
             }
  }
```

I am creating a dataframe to write to bigquery.

Here is my code.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery


import pandas
import pandas_gbq

URL = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = HTTPBasicAuth('name', 'password')

r = requests.get(url=URL, auth=auth)

# Extracting data in JSON format
data = json.loads(json.dumps(r.json()))
# data = r.json()
print(type(data))
offset = str(data['data']['offset'])
json_data = data['data']['items']

type(json_data)

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
    'offset': offset,
    'json_data': json_data

)
# df['json_data'] = df['json_data'].astype('string')

client = bigquery.Client(project='ncau-data-newsquery-sit')
table_id = 'sdm_adpoint.testfapi1'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("offset", "STRING"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("json_data", "STRING", "REPEATED")
            # , index=[0]

        ],
        autodetect=False

)

df.head()

pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, table_id, project_id='ncau-data-newsquery-sit', if_exists='append')
```

I have made dataframe out of this like below:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXs0s.png)

But when I write to bigquery using

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, table_id, project_id='ncau-data-newsquery-sit', if_exists='append')
```

It throws the below error:

> ArrowTypeError: Could not convert {'id': '6biewd5a',......

To overcome this, I tried this:

```
df['json_data'] = df['json_data'].astype('string')
```

It’s working, but it’s merging all rows as one, and writing each letter in a separate row.

I want data to be written as a row, the same way as displayed in a Pandas dataframe.

I tried to write to Bigquery using

`pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, table_id, project_id='ncau-data-newsquery-sit', if_exists='append')`

But it throws an error

> ArrowTypeError: Could not convert {'id': '6biewd5a',......

Then I tried

```
df['json_data'] = df['json_data'].astype('string')
```

But it’s merging all rows as one, and writing each letter in separate rows.

I want data to be written as a row, the same way as displayed in Pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON schema is very similar to the schema given here in a Google Cloud Platform example:
*[Example schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#example_schema)*

So you will have to make the below change to your schema definition in your code.

For the items schema, you will have to define the schema as below:

```
bigquery.SchemaField(
        "items",
        "RECORD",
        mode="REPEATED",
        fields=[
                bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
                bigquery.SchemaField("title", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
             ],
        )
```

Comment: Hi Bihag, I dont want  to parse the json and seperate it. Check my dataframe, the image which I have uploaded. I want to have offset as one column and all json as other column called json_data.